# unable to imitate error interface of Golang

Tags: go, interface

I am trying to imitate what is happening in error in a similar piece of code, first piece of code prints --- log second does not why? or in other words I am trying to understand how Error() method got called without explicitly calling.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type argError struct {
    arg  int
    prob string
}

func (e *argError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d ---- %s", e.arg, e.prob)
}

func f2(arg int) (int, error) {
        return -1, &argError{arg, "can't work with it"}
}

func main() {
    a,b := f2(42)
    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(b)
}



package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myerr interface {
    Apple() string
}

type dummy struct {
    age  int
    name string
}

func (d *dummy) Apple() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d --- %s", d.age, d.name)
}

func f1(arg int) (string, myerr) {
    return "f1", &dummy{arg, "ret"}
}

func main() {
    i, j := f1(42)
    fmt.Println(i)
    fmt.Println(j)
}
```

Comment: [It's in the `fmt` docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/): "If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string"

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, your type has to implement the `error` interface by having a `Error` method. I recommend adjusting your `myerr` interface to embed `error`, like so:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myerr interface {
    error                    // <--- note: embedding 'error' here
    Apple() string
}

type dummy struct {
    age  int
    name string
}

func (d *dummy) Apple() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d --- %s", d.age, d.name)
}

// <--- note: implement the 'error' interface for the 'dummy' type
func (d *dummy) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d ---- %s", d.age, d.name)
}

func f1(arg int) (string, myerr) {
    return "f1", &dummy{arg, "ret"}
}

func main() {
    i, j := f1(42)
    fmt.Println(i)
    fmt.Println(j)
}
```

This should invoke the `Error` method of `j` as you'd expect.

You can try it [on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9B6-SJ4emq5).